# Privatising avatar discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Hi I'm struggling on how to prevent members from obtaining another members avatar by using a role as you can see members with the role Private Avatar will have their avatar protected. This is how I'm coding this in .py

```
class Avatar:
    """Returns members avatar."""

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    @commands.cooldown(5, 60, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def avatar(self, context, member: discord.Member):
        """Returns members avatar."""

        role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name="Private Avatar")
        author = context.message.author.mention
        mention = member.mention

        if role in member.roles:
            pa = "This members avatar is private"
            await self.bot.say(pa)
            return

        avatar = "{0} here is {1}'s avatar"

        u = member.avatar_url
        url = process_avatar(u)
        embed = discord.Embed(description=avatar.format(author, mention), colour=discord.Colour.blue())
        embed.set_image(url=u)
        await self.bot.say(embed=embed)
```

The line of code I'm struggling with is this line

```
 if role in member.roles:
            pa = "This members avatar is private"
            await self.bot.say(pa)
            return
```

This should basically output the message "This members avatar is private" without retrieving the avatar but it still retrieves the avatar with the message.

Your help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're over-complicating it. Just use `else:`, like this:

```js
class Avatar:
    """Returns members avatar."""

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    @commands.cooldown(5, 60, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def avatar(self, context, member: discord.Member):
        """Returns members avatar."""
        
        role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name="Private Avatar")
        author = context.message.author.mention
        mention = member.mention
        
        if role in member.roles:
            pa = "This members avatar is private"
            await self.bot.say(pa)
        else:
  
            avatar = "{0} here is {1}'s avatar"

            u = member.avatar_url
            url = process_avatar(u)
            embed = discord.Embed(description=avatar.format(author, mention), colour=discord.Colour.blue())
            embed.set_image(url=u)
            await self.bot.say(embed=embed)
```

*P.S.: In theory, your code should work. Unless there's something I'm not seeing wrong, that is. I must also note that just because the bot won't fetch it, doesn't mean the client can't. Avatars are public.*

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and that still fetches the avatar which is what I don't want to do. I unsure whats going wrong here.

Comment: It means your check isn't running correctly. Maybe try adding some `print` statements in various places to check things like if your search role is being found properly or if the member has the same role as your search role. e.g. `print(role)` should return `<discord.role.Role id="..." ...>` if it found it, and if it prints `None` then something is wrong.

Comment: I figured it out to be a role id issue. Thank you for your help

Comment: Glad you figured it out @troxie